# SUMO: Secondary destination if there is no available route

Tags: xml, simulation, traffic, reroute

I am running sumo to simulate a potential road cut scenario during an evacuation (multiple road cuts). I have installed reroute for those scheduled road cuts. However, for some vehicles, there will not be any available routes to the desired destination.  According to the manual, if there is no alternative route, vehicles will continue their old routes and ignore the closed edge.

I am wondering if there is possible to set a secondary destination? If so, could someone show me how to? I have tried to search online or manual, but I couldn’t find any.

If the secondary destination is not possible, could it be possible to make the vehicle stop and terminate its journey?

I copied the code of reroute.add.xml and a simple road cut figure. Hope it helps. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

[image]

```
    <additional>
        <rerouter id="rerouter1" edges="2" probability="1">
            <interval begin="1" end="2000">
                <closingReroute id="1" allow="ignoring"/>
                <destProbReroute id="107" probability="1"/>
            </interval>
        </rerouter>  
        <rerouter id="rerouter2" edges="3" probability="1">
            <interval begin="1" end="2000">
                <closingReroute id="11" allow="ignoring"/>
                <destProbReroute id="107" probability="1"/>
            </interval>
        </rerouter>  

    </additional>
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is only valid for the current nightly build of SUMO. Since there are changes to the last release your mileage may vary.

1. There is currently no possiblity to add a secondary destination when using a rerouter. If you need this functionality you could use TraCI though but then you would need to write a separate program.
2. Considering route termination there are two cases:

   a) The destination edge is a closed edge. If this is the case the route will be temrinated with an appropriate warning. Please note that you can give the special "edge id" `keepDestination` to keep the destination edge for the vehicle.

   b) The destination edge is not a closed one. Depending on the permissions of the closed edge the vehicle will wait at the last edge of the route it still can drive and may possibly get teleported after waiting too long.

So if you can extend your list of closed edges to cover also the ones which are not reachable anymore you might be able to fix the scenario, if not (because it is dependent on the vehicles) you need to do it yourself using TraCI.

I also opened a ticket http://sumo.dlr.de/trac.wsgi/ticket/2223